# JPA generates sql query tables out of order in the FROM clause

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I've run into a problem several times where a left join in my JPA query generates a SQL query where the tables are out of proper order in the FROM clause and can't be executed.

A simple example with some pseudo entities:

```
CAR {
  int id,
  string model
}

OWNER {
  Car car,
  string owner_name
}

BORROWER {
  Car car,
  string borrower_name
}
```

JPA query:

```
SELECT O, B
FROM OWNER O
LEFT JOIN BORROWER B ON ( B.CAR = O.CAR )
```

Generated SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM owner_table
LEFT JOIN borrower_table ON ( borrower_table.car_id = car_table.id )
, car_table
WHERE car_table.id = owner_table.car_id
```

This will not run because the car_table is declared after being referenced in the join. Is there anything I can do?

Running EclipseLink on Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could structure you jpa query using the old style join:

```
SELECT O, B
FROM OWNER O, BORROWER B, CAR C
WHERE (O.car_id = B.car_id and B.car_id = C.car_id) 
       or (O.car_id is null)
       or (O.car_id != B.car_id)
```